# When a returned slice is not necessary to be static?

Tags: rust

I appreciate it if someone could help me on this problem.
Would you please take a look on this Rust code:

```
fn main() {
    let _s0 = "s0";
    println!("{}", get_slice_1());
    println!("{}", get_slice_2());
    println!("{}", get_slice_3(_s0));
}

fn get_slice_1() -> &str {
    let _s1 = "s1";
    return _s1;
}

fn get_slice_2() -> &'static str {
    let _s2 = "s2";
    return _s2;
}

fn get_slice_3(_x: &str) -> &str {
    let _s3 = "s3";
    return _s3;
}
```

The reference of the first function get_slice_1 has a problem that is fixed in the second function get_slice_2. So far no problem.

But the get_slice_3 function is very strange to me because the input _x: &str seems to have no role, but neither does the get_slice_1 issue. Why static reference is not necessary in the last function (get_slice_3)?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/lifetime_coercion.html

Answer (score 1):

`get_slice_2` specifies explicitly that the return value is valid for `'static`.

`get_slice_1` and `get_slice_3` use [elided lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html), a convenience mechanism so that you don't have to explicitly specify lifetimes in simple scenarios.

`get_slice_3` is valid by the second rule:

> If there is exactly one input lifetime position (elided or not), that lifetime is assigned to all elided output lifetimes.

And so is equivalent to `fn get_slice_3<'a>(_x: &'a str) -> &'a str`. Note that in this case, rust will prevent the returned `str` from outliving what was passed to `_x`, even though in reality it's a `&'static str`.

`get_slice_1`, lacking any input lifetimes but containing an output lifetime, does not match any of the rules, and so it is rejected.